# Some Web services Pages are not called from android application

Tags: android, web-services

I am calling php web service from android which send json data to android application.
Some web service pages called successfully but some pages are not called.

Even i try to access from the mobile browser but in that also i can not access the page.

Can anyone help me what is the problem ???